# See all the recognised monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

We are working in a flex desk environment with a different monitor on each desk. I've noticed that Windows (7) keeps track of all monitors. For example, if I've set up one external monitor on 'duplicate', but another on 'extend'. If I reconnect weeks later, he will stil remember this particular setting. This works for display port connections and it will probably not hold for VGA.

I was wondering if there is somewhere a place where I could see all these settings together. I've checked device manager, but that only has the current connected devices. There must be a list somewhere, I assume in the registry, but I couldn't find it. Where could I find this list?

Also, how does the unique identification work? Is it part of the display port protocol?

Comment: Why would this not work with VGA? It's likely using the information provided by [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) and/or [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel). In addition it might be depended on your graphics driver. It's likely stored in some registry key. [What registry key or windows file determines where monitors are placed in a multi monitor environment?](https://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult)

Comment: This answer shows exactly where you can find them https://superuser.com/a/159720/588544