# Find offset in dual monitor arrangement in Windows 7 (and up)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

If two monitors are not aligned on the top or bottom edge, is there a way to find out the value of the offset on either one of the edges? I want to do it without purely visual inspection using a screen ruler like [jruler](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) because I need it to be exact (+/- 0 pixels). I'm looking for an Win7 and up solution (those can be separate solutions as well, mainly I'm focused on Win7).

I have no problem with 3rd party applications, if it's not possible to do without, but I prefer "portable"ones (no installation needed).

To make sure what "offset" I'm referring to here's a screenshot in which the bottom and top offset of two monitors is marked (note: this is a Win10 screenshot).

[image: visualize offset in monitor alignment]

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here:

[What registry key or windows file determines where monitors are placed in a multi monitor environment?](https://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult)

[Relevant registry keys for Window 7 and up are to be found here:](https://superuser.com/a/159720/1150196)

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\
```

Look for Position.cx and Position.cy in each of the subfolders.

Comment: Each monitor is in there multiple times, how do I find the right regkey?

Answer (score 0):

How about opening any conventional (rectangular window) application and moving it so that it straddles both monitors?  If you care about top-of-window alignment, then move the app to the top of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for you're suggestion. I'm not sure what you mean? How does this tell me the length of the offset?

Comment: @Albin:  Either measure the onscreen offset (like with a tape measure/ruler), or reposition the monitor(s) until it is aligned and then measure how far it moved.  (Maybe I don't understand the question.)

Comment: yeah, I'm already using jruler (see question), although it's possible to get an estimated measurement (+/- 2pixels) if find it rather cumbersome (because of shadows etc.), if you have a more "exact" method that's easy to apply please let me know. I guess I could switch to "classic" view, maybe that works better, but I rather have a solution which leaves the Windows settings intact. A screenshot would be good, so I know what you mean.