# Perfectly center second smaller monitor in Windows 10

Tags: windows, display

When I use Windows Settings -> Display -> Rearrange your displays, there isn't a way to perfectly center a smaller full HD display below 4k monitor, it is always a bit off when you try to drag the second display to the center, there is no snap to center, only to the edges.

Is there some tool or hack that could help with this?

Comment: Why do want t center it perfectly? Does something work/look differently besides the preview? Or does your setup not even allow approximate placement? Maybe there’s another way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, try manually adjusting the placement values in the registry. You can use SysInternals `procmon` while making some adjustments to learn which keys are used.

This SU answer gives some ideas for where to start: https://superuser.com/a/106757/167191