# Windows10: How to keep the display/monitor disabled while operating remotely?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, remote-desktop, remote

I have tried disable or uninstall the 'Generic PnP Monitor' in Device Manager, totally no change.

I also tried some commandlines using postmessage function to set SC_MONITORPOWER to 2, this method succeeded to turn off the display, but the monitor was on when I move the mouse...

So is there a way to keep the display/monitor off while I operate the computer remotely? like unconnect the monitor, or make the Windows stop sending signals to monitor?

(Not physical power button method in our case)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps send display output to a non-existent device? https://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult

Answer (score 0):

> Windows10: How to keep the display/monitor disabled while operating
> remotely?
>
> I have tried disable or uninstall the 'Generic PnP Monitor' in Device
> Manager, totally no change.
>
> I also tried some commandlines using postmessage function to set
> SC_MONITORPOWER to 2, this method succeeded to turn off the display,
> but the monitor was on when I move the mouse...
>
> So is there a way to keep the display/monitor off while I operate the
> computer remotely? like unconnect the monitor, or make the Windows
> stop sending signals to monitor?
>
> (Not physical power button method in our case)

Having done this and faced this issue, if away for a week or more, I unplug the Monitor before leaving.

Nothing else has worked. Monitors tend to have soft power buttons which is one reason why just turning the monitor off may or may not work.